# Adding a .dll to a NetBeans 7.0 C project. Unable to view .dll

Tags: dll, netbeans7.0, libsndfile

I am trying to read a .wav file and hence need to include the libsndfile binary in my project. I am using NetBeans 7.0 and the Tools->Library->Add new library option doesnt work since the Add library button is disabled.

I tried adding the path of the header file to the Project->Build properties and the code compiled. But when I try to add the .dll in a similar way via Project->Linker properties NetBeans is unable to find the .dll. If i navigate to the folder from MyComputer->..i can see the .dll/ However NetBeans doesn't display it.

I am using a Win 7 64 bit machine & I have setup the appropriate libsndfile binary. Been at it for a day now. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Neeraj

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283203/reading-a-wav-file-using-libsndfile-in-c

Answer (score 0):

DLL doesnotrequires setting of class path. So you can load a DLL from local file system. Copy the DLL and go to the file explorer tab strip and paste the file.

Comment: Tried puttin the .dll in the project root..doesn't work,library functions undefined error persists..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check that your compiler version (32 or 64 bit) matches libsndfile version. I suppose you did it correctly.

I also suppose you correctly added the `sndfile.h` to the include path.

You will need two library files actually. I think you forgot the one to compile properly.

### Compiling and Linking (`.lib` file)

Note that Netbeans 7.0 doesn't accept .lib files and you need to link the .lib file for your project to compile. So, in `C:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\lib` you need to copy `libsndfile-1.lib` and rename the `.lib` extension to `.a`.

Then, in **Poject Properties > Build > Linker > Additional Libraries Directories** add the path to the `\lib` directory. For me it's `Program Files/Mega-Nerd/libsndfile/lib`.

A few lines below, you'll have **Poject Properties > Build > Linker > Libraries**. Specify the location of the library file named `libsndfile-1.a`, for me it's `C:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\lib\libsndfile-1.a`.

Now it should at least compile.

### Executing (`.dll`)

Now, it likely will not execute even if it compiled. That's because the `.dll` file is needed to execute the final `.exe`. Simply copy the `libsndfile-1.dll` file (for me it's in `C:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\bin`) to your project, next to the `.exe` file. For me, it's in `C:\proj\dist\Debug\Cygwin-Windows\proj.exe`.

*Edit: I checked with the today's 8.2 version of NetBeans, and the procedure is exactly the same.*