# Reading a .wav file using libsndfile in C

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, libsndfile

I want to read a .wav file in C similar to what Matlab's wavread command does. I came across this library http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/ that seems to be the solution. But can someone explain how to install this library so that I may use its functions? (I've never done that before so please help). I tried including the sndfile.h but errors like `cannot find -lsndfile-1.lib`is popping up. I believe it is because I'm not integrating the library properly.

Comment: What is your environment (compiler and IDE if you use any)?

Comment: MinGW compiler on codeBlocks IDE

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is to install the library (I chose `libsndfile-1.0.28-w32-setup.exe` because I run code::blocks with the pre-installed MinGW `codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe` and I think it has 32bit compiler by default) and locate these three files:

> `sndfile.h` (for me it is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\include`)
>
> `libsndfile-1.lib` (for me `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\lib`)
>
> `libsndfile-1.dll` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\bin`)

Then you right click on your project and go to **Build options... > Search directories > Compiler** and add the address of `sndfile.h` directory.

[image: compiler directory]

Then, you go to **Build options... >Linker settings > Link libraries:** and add the address of `libsndfile-1.lib`.

[image: link lib]

Finally, you copy the `libsndfile-1.dll` next to where the `.exe` file will be created (for me it's in `MyProject\bin\Debug`).

Here is a simple example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sndfile.h"

int main(void)
{
  char *inFileName;
  SNDFILE *inFile;
  SF_INFO inFileInfo;
  int fs;

  inFileName = "noise.wav";

  inFile = sf_open(inFileName, SFM_READ, &inFileInfo);
  sf_close(inFile);

  fs = inFileInfo.samplerate;
  printf("Sample Rate = %d Hz\n", fs);

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> `Sample Rate = 44100 Hz`